# Is topological insulators are quantum meta-material?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, soft-question

I am trying to understand the definitions of meta-material, quantum meta-material and topological insulators. Individually each definitions is explained in wikipedia pages.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_metamaterial

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_insulator

It appears these terms came from different branches of physics from electromagnetic and  condensed matter. Is there a relation between quantum meta-material and topological insulator?

Comment: You can have topological insulators in regular materials without meta engineering it. e.g. bismuth telluride